# Has the arithmetic for exotic (unsigned float with positive exponent) number format been solved?

Tags: reference-request, floating-point

The data type is a doubly unsigned float. This is where the value and exponent are both strictly positive. The range of this number should include $0$ and $[1, ~2^{\text{exponent}})$, skipping all values between 0 and 1.

My use case for this would be implementing a certain incremental game (Cookie Clicker) for an older game console (NES) where space might be an issue, the numbers could get large, and more complex operations are likely unnecessary.

I have looked at Steve Wozniak's and another person's implementation of floats in 6502 assembly and while they may work for me, I can't shake that this specific idea has to have been someone's PhD project, right?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit, what do you mean by "solved"? Are you looking for references (then a [tag:reference-request] is applicable) or some implementation?

Comment: Yes. I would like to know if there is some implementation of this specific format that I could use in a project with limited computer resources.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the arithmetic operations required on these nonnegative integers?

Comment: Re "has to have been someone's PhD project": Extremely unlikely, as the proposed unsigned floating-point arithmetic does not require any research; it is a programming exercise. For example, for ease of handling, define a format using significand of 24 stored bits normalized to $[0.5, 1)$ (as in VAX floating-point of old) and 8-bit unsigned exponent $e$, where $e=0$ indicates zero, and $e=255$ is used for infinity / NaNs. Existing software implementations of IEEE-754 `binary32` arithmetic could be modified for this. Representable range would be $[1,2.9\cdot 10^{76})$, 7 decimal digits accuracy

Comment: @hardmath Yes, Addition, Subtraction and Multiplication. I suppose I asked too specific but without many details regarding my use case. The game (Cookie Clicker) has around 130 values that would require this number format, and since the console (NES) only has 2kb of variable space (I'm still learning), reducing the word size of the number to the smallest set of bits would be ideal.

Comment: @njuffa Maybe I am overthinking it. Omitting the exponent bias and sign bit should save 2 bits for the Mantissa. A typical gameplay has a player add numbers of >=6 magnitudes difference together, so I should need >=16 bits for that section. With 8 bits of exponent where `e = 0` I should be able to bring a player to the end of the main game (~10^72). I suppose a 3/4 word float is my use case if the full precision float is too much?

If I used integers, the end-game would require ~240 bits to store the largest of them, and a bigInt like that is already a lot of data to store losslessly.